# Fade in effect on document ready doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fade

The fade effect being used in the showed Jquery doesn't work, why?

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.Game').fadeIn(500);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">
  <h1 class="Game">Darkness Island</h1>
  <h2>Available soon</h2>
  <button class="Download">Download</button>
  <button class="Details">See details</button>
</div>
```

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: none;` on "Game" div to start with.

Also keep the script tag at the end of html

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.Game').fadeIn(500);
   });
```

And most impportantly, include jquery in the head tag.

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="text">
    <h1 class="Game" style="display: none;">Darkness Island</h1>
    <h2>Available soon</h2>
    <button class="Download">Download</button>
    <button class="Details">See details</button>
</div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
$('.Game').fadeIn(500);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you can use fadeIn function, the item shouldn't be visible.

this example should work

```
$(function(){
  $(document).ready(function () {
   $('.Game').fadeOut();
   $('.Game').fadeIn(500);
  });
});
```

Comment: You can also initialize game class as display only ``.Game {display:none}